# Conditions for a symmetric matrix to be equivalent to another one using orthogonal matrices?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

I am looking for conditions under which a symmetric matrix $S$ could be equivalent to another symmetric matrix $Y$, so that $Y=B^{-1}SA$, with the added properties that $S$ and $Y$ have non-zero determinant, and $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal (so in effect we also have $Y={}^tBSA$).

I know that since $Y$ and $S$ are of maximum rank, they are equivalent, but can we always find $A$ and $B$ that are orthogonal ?

In fact I am trying to answer a different question that I think is equivalent (maybe this formulation is clearer/easier) : given $S$ symmetric and invertible, and $P,Q$ two orthogonal matrices, can we find $X$ orthogonal and $Y$ symmetric so that ${}^tQSP={}^tXYX$ ?

The questions seem equivalent because if there exists $A,B$ such that $P=AX$ and $Q=BX$ (necessarily $A,B$ would be orthogonal) then we would have $Y={}^tBSA$ but I'm not sure that $Y$ would be symmetric...

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, any symmetric (real) matrix is diagonalizable by orthogonal matrices. So every equivalence class is represented by a diagonal matrix. In particular, any two matrices will be equivalent if they have the same eigenvalues.

From there it gets a little subtle. I think the resulting quotient space is basically a Weyl chamber in the symmetric space $SL_n/SO_n$. In that case two equivalent matrices must indeed have the same (unordered) eigenvalues, up to sign.

Edit: forgot that you can switch the sign of each eigenvalue

Comment: Agree, disagree, agree, don't know ^^.
Diagonalizable, sure. But the equivalence class is more loose than that : take the trivial example $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac12\end{pmatrix}$, they aren't represented by a single diagonal matrix (or have I misunderstood your argument ?)... The class is represented by the rank rather.
But yes, if they're similar (same eigenvalues), then they are equivalent, just not the reverse.
Haven't thought about quotient spaces, will check, thanks.

Comment: I guess you could represent each class with a diagonal matrix of each rank, so if that what you meant, my bad.

Comment: I thought $B$ and $A$ are required to be orthogonal? Your matrix on the left has determinant $-2$, so it is not orthogonal. Also, I don't claim a diagonal matrix is the only diagonal matrix in its equivalence class. Any other permutation of the order is in the same equivalence class. But I do claim that's it. (actually up to the sign of each eigenvalue- I forgot that).

Comment: -2 and 1/2 then it's orthogonal, resulting in diagonal(1/2, 2). Still not seing it. I'm intrigued though.

Comment: well, now it has the right determinant, but it is still not orthogonal. the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix always have modulus 1.

Comment: Ok I see now, I must be tired (it's late where I am - any excuse, right ;-)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your question can be answered,  if you look at the eigen decomposition of matrices. In case of symmetric matrices, the two factors are orthogonal and are the inverse of each other.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by orthogonal and inverse factors, but I'll mull it over, thanks.